# How to update all cells in all tables with datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have multiple datatables in the same page where their class name is 'datatable-responsive'. I want to update the contente of each cell in each table...

```
$('.datatable-responsive').each( function(i){
  var table = $(this).dataTable();

  table.cell('.normal-1').data(valToSet).draw();
});
```

When I inspect thru firebug the "tables", I get 3 tables but it's not entering in the loop. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sincos/fnj0eb4m/5/)

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your markup as well, so we don't have to build our own test case in order to help you.

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle, is that you want? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`invalidate()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().invalidate()) the cell in order to update the internal preprocessed sorting for the column :

```js
var table = $(this).DataTable();
table.cell(selector).data(randomNewVal).invalidate().draw();
```

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/fnj0eb4m/11/**

Comment: @sincos, you are welcome! Was in doubt if it should be a comment, but now there is a short answer with a fiddle, there is no real duplicates for the post I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to target the child element incorrectly. Instead of using `table.cell('.normal-1')` try using `$(table).find('.normal-1');`

I substituted this in your fiddle and it's targeting the correct element however I'm still getting an error on the console saying `valToSet is not defined` which I think might be a different issue. Hope that helps!

**Edit**

Also... the reason why your loop isn't completing is because of the `valToSet not defined` error is stopping the loop. Comment this line out and you will see your tables in the console.

Comment: It's working to change the value, but when I sort the column1, it doesn't take care about the new value, the sorting is not working... this is the reason why I want to use datatables function to change the value and then draw it...